# Google Earth API, KML on local Web Server

Tags: api, webserver, kml, google-earth-plugin

I am trying to load a .kml from a webserver that we use to host our company intranet on, will this work?!

The GE API loads up fine but does not currently display the KML file?! Also I cant seem to paste the code without bits being missed off, any idea why this might be?!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using absolute URL to the resources? i.e. 
'http://192.168.1.2/whatever.kml'

Or try to use google hosted kml to see if the code isn't working or the kml is wrong
for example:
'http://sketchup.google.com/3dwarehouse/download?mid=28b27372e2016cca82bddec656c63017&rtyp=k2'

Comment: Paco, Thanks for the response! It turned out it was a permissions issue with the web server! Glad to have it up and running, much better than end users having to open up google earth separately!